# Ошибка при запуске консоли под .NET Framework на Debian

Tags: c#, debian, mono, vknet

Появляется ошибка при запуске ConsoleApp2.exe на Debian x86

Запускаю

> mono ConsoleApp2.exe

Вывод:

> 17:14:00 VkApi VkApi Initialization successfully
>   17:14:00 VkApi Старт авторизации
>   17:14:00 VkApi Шаг 1. Открытие диалога авторизации
>   Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.WebCall..ctor (System.String url, VkNet.Utils.Cookies cookies, IWebProxy webProxy, Boolean allowAutoRedirect) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.WebCall.MakeCall (System.String url, IWebProxy webProxy) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.Browser.OpenAuthDialog (UInt64 appId, VkNet.Enums.Filters.Settings settings) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.Browser.Authorize (IApiAuthParams authParams) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.VkApi.BaseAuthorize (IApiAuthParams authParams) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.VkApi.AuthorizeWithAntiCaptcha (IApiAuthParams authParams) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.VkApi.Authorize (IApiAuthParams params) [0x00000] in :0
>     at Казино.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.WebCall..ctor (System.String url, VkNet.Utils.Cookies cookies, IWebProxy webProxy, Boolean allowAutoRedirect) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.WebCall.MakeCall (System.String url, IWebProxy webProxy) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.Browser.OpenAuthDialog (UInt64 appId, VkNet.Enums.Filters.Settings settings) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.Utils.Browser.Authorize (IApiAuthParams authParams) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.VkApi.BaseAuthorize (IApiAuthParams authParams) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.VkApi.AuthorizeWithAntiCaptcha (IApiAuthParams authParams) [0x00000] in :0
>     at VkNet.VkApi.Authorize (IApiAuthParams params) [0x00000] in :0
>     at Казино.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Версия mono:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Mono 3.2.8 does not have the System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll as part of its full .NET framework implementation." Отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581591/system-diagnostics-tracing-in-mono

Comment: И вообще, на смену Моно есть NET Core.

Comment: @JaponDemon пробовал, для него архитектура х64 нужна

Comment: Итого, сборка `VkNet` не работает под моно. Обращайтесь к разработчику сборки.